# Bold UTF-8 characters in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, utf-8, fonts

So problem which I can't solve for a while is that in Internet Explorer utf-8 characters are bold. Here is code example:

```
.section.about-houses .tabs-block .tab-content p {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    line-height: 2.2;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #373737;
}
```

and this is a result:

[image]

Comment: All characters are UTF-8. The problem is on your font. Character not in the default font are searched on an other font. So: get a font which includes also Latin accented characters.

Comment: Write an answer and I will accept it, because you are right. I have included font from Google without Latin support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All characters are UTF-8. The problem is on your fonts: it seems that your main font doesn't have full support of accented characters, so your browser will use an alternate font for the missing characters. To me, it seems that it is still a non bold font, but with more weight compared to your very light default font.

So I would recommend you to look for a font which includes all Latin characters. A complete Unicode font will be too large (and so slow), but you know better what script you need, so you can select only a good font (e.g. for Latin script). On Web fonts (CSS), you can specify the code points (and intervals).